# What are the NASA Moon and Jupiter map images?

Tags: starfield

When you first load up Starfield, this text is displayed:

[image: start up text Relevant portion: Moon maps Image Credit: NASA's Scientific Visualization Studio. Jupiter maps Image Credit: NASA Goddard Space Flight Center, Space Telescope Science Institute.]

The part I am interested in is:

> Moon maps Image Credit: NASA's Scientific Visualization Studio. Jupiter maps Image Credit: NASA Goddard Space Flight Center, Space Telescope Science Institute.

What are these NASA map images? Where are they found in the game?

Comment: I would imagine it's the look of the actual planet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These images are used in the Juno's Gambit questline. This is a random encounter related to Ryujin Industries, but you do not have to join in order to get the encounter. That said, it helps.

> Juno is an old AI that has gone "haywire" according to the crew and you are tasked with killing it. Upon dialogue with the AI (she uses these images while speaking with you)... you make the final call whether to save her, kill the crew, or attempt to save everyone.